# Readily available examples of documentation built with Dokka?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-dokka

The official [documentation on Dokka](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/blob/master/README.md) says that Dokka can output result in different formats:

> #### Output formats
>
> - `html` - minimalistic html format used by default, Java classes are translated to Kotlin
> - `javadoc` - looks like normal Javadoc, Kotlin classes are translated to Java
> - `html-as-java` - looks like `html`, but Kotlin classes are translated to Java
> - `markdown` - markdown structured as `html`, Java classes are translated to Kotlin
>
>   - `gfm` - GitHub flavored markdown
>   - `jekyll` - Jekyll compatible markdown
> - `kotlin-website*` - internal format used for documentation on [kotlinlang.org](https://kotlinlang.org)

While I've seen some of the formats on kotlinlang.org (the Standard Library and the Language Guide) I have yet to see others.

Are there any links to documentation generated in `html`, `javadoc`, or `html-as-java` formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, 
for `html` please see https://gradle.github.io/kotlin-dsl-docs/api/,
`javadoc` uses `HtmlDoclet` from your JDK (it currently does not work with JDK > 8), so it is just ordinary javadoc and `html-as-java` looks like `html`, the only difference is that Kotlin types are translated to Java (so you get `Foo extends Bar` instead of `Foo : Bar`). 
Also please note we're working on a new version of dokka with all the formats rewritten and prettier